# Data safety in ext4 as external HDD drive in ubuntu as main OS

Tags: external-hdd, ext4

HI pardon me for asking
I have an external 1tb HDD drive that formated in ext4 my main system is in ext4 SSD either
the thing is I wanted to know that is my data are safe not like really safe but just okay to store general files like music, video, etc in my HDD.
I know ext4 have an issue when it comes to power failure, risk of data loss,etc.
could somebody please help me to better understanding cause I'm using Ubuntu as my main driver and it really concerns me.

I already check my HDD ext4 journal is enable

tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep feature

Filesystem features: has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
here

do I need the writeback for a safe guarantee probably it's gonna be a slow performance on the hard drive but is it necessary?
thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate "I know ext4 have an issue when it comes to power failure". I know that ext4 is one of the safest FS for these cases. If you need more "safety", do backups.

Comment: Been using ext4 since 10.04, have not had any issues(yet).  If concerned about power failures, can use a backup power system till safe power down.  Hard drives do fail sometimes, mainly before you make backups.

Comment: thank you for the answer